# config.qml in Wallpaper Plugin KDE plasma

Tags: qt, qml, kde-plasma, plasmoid

I am developing a Wallpaper Plugin for KDE Plasma. I have coded all the effects and tested them. It runs well. But while coding the configuration file, the config didn't show up at all in Configure Wallpaper. When I choose another plugin, it shows up and when I again choose the this one, the configuration doesn't load up.
Here's the code.

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0 as QtControls

// for "units"
import org.kde.plasma.core 2.0 as PlasmaCore


ColumnLayout {
    id: root
    property alias cfg_DisplayText: textField.text

    RowLayout {
        spacing: units.largeSpacing / 2

        // To allow aligned integration in the settings form,
        // "formAlignment" is a property injected by the config containment
        // which defines the offset of the value fields
        QtControls.Label {
            Layout.minimumWidth: width
            Layout.maximumWidth: width
            width: formAlignment - units.largeSpacing
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight

            // use i18nd in config QML, as the default textdomain is set to that of the config container
            text: i18nd("plasma_wallpaper_org.kde.plasma.random", "Choose Effect")
        }
           QtControls.ComboBox {
        id: resizeComboBox
        Kirigami.FormData.label: i18ndc("plasma_wallpaper_org.kde.plasma.random", "@label:listbox", "Centre Logo Glow:")
        model: [
                    {
                        'label': i18ndc("plasma_wallpaper_org.kde.plasma.random", "@item:inlistbox", "Central Logo Shown"),
                       
                    },
                    {
                        'label': i18ndc("plasma_wallpaper_org.kde.plasma.random", "@item:inlistbox", "Central Logo Focused"),
                        
                    },
                    {
                        'label': i18ndc("plasma_wallpaper_org.kde.plasma.random", "@item:inlistbox", "Central Logo Colored"),
                        
                    },
                    {
                        'label': i18ndc("plasma_wallpaper_org.kde.plasma.random", "@item:inlistbox", "Left to deside"),
                        
                    },
                    {
                        'label': i18ndc("plasma_wallpaper_org.kde.plasma.random", "@item:inlistbox", "Left to decide"),
                     
                    }
                ]
           }

    Item { // tighten layout
        Layout.fillHeight: true
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means there is an error in your config.

You can try restarting KDE in a konsole session, so you can see the log:

killall plasmashell; kstart5 plasmashell

If it isn't obvious what is going wrong from the log output, try commenting out most of your config.qml, then uncomment elements one at a time, until you figure out which element is causing the problem.